# Python 3 で、文字列と整数が混在するリストから負数をint型で取得したい

Tags: python, python3

Python 3 で、リストに含まれている負数の数字をint型として格納したい。
isdecimalは負数に対応してないということで、以下のようにして正規表現を用いて負の値を操作したのですが、他にいい方法があるのではと思い質問しました。

```
import re
s = 'ADD 3 -11'.split()

r = re.compile(r'-?\d')
for i in range(len(s)):
    try:
        if r.search(s[i]):
            s[i] = int(s[i])
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(s)
```

Comment: `'3.0'` も "文字列" として扱いますか？ それとも "整数" として扱いますか？

Comment: 本家 Stack Overflow 上の関連質問です: ["Python: Check if a string represents an int, Without using Try/Except?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1265665/5989200)

Comment: `+1` とかも考慮すると、`r = re.compile(r'[+-]?\d+')` とする方が良いのではないかと思います。また、`s` を直接書き変えずに、`s = 'ADD 3 -11'; t = [int(i) if r.match(i) else i for i in s.split()]` などとするとか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

何を「文字列」や「整数」として扱うかにもよりますが、最終的に `int()` を使うのであれば、最初から `int()` を使ってみてエラーが出るかどうかで分岐する方法があります。

```
>>> s = 'STRING 3 -11 +2 3.14 5.0 0xFF 00101100'.split()
>>> s
['STRING', '3', '-11', '+2', '3.14', '5.0', '0xFF', '00101100']
>>> for i in range(len(s)):
...   try:
...     s[i] = int(s[i])
...   except ValueError:
...     pass
... 
>>> s
['STRING', 3, -11, 2, '3.14', '5.0', '0xFF', 101100]
```

厳密にどういう文字列が整数値に変換されるのかについては、[`int()` のマニュアル](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/functions.html#int)をご覧ください。